# Why does my LED strip list maximum power as 45W while the LEDs added makes 37.5W?

Tags: power, led-strip

My 5-meter LED strip with 30 WS2812B per meter lists "Maximum power: 45W". However, if I calculate it I get:

```
WS2812B max current draw * voltage * number of LEDs
= 50 mA * 5 V * 150
= 37.5 W
```

Is the rest of the power due to voltage drop along the wires? Do regulations require a margin of error? Is there any other effect that I'm not taking into account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They are calculating the max current draw per segment at 60 mA not 50.

Comment: You're right, thank you! Do you know why they're not taking into account the 5m of wire? Is that power loss negligible in comparison?

Comment: the voltage drop across that would reduce the current draw at the far end. But mostly because it depends on how you use it or wire it. Inject power at both ends to avoid the voltage drop.

Comment: @MrBuisson. Completely wrong! The input voltage for the chip is not in any way related to the Blue LED Vf (or the Red-Green LEDs either).    The  WS2812B does not have linear regulators for the LED drive. Each chip has an onboard switching regulator which produces 12v internally for all three LEDs  and a CC driver for each channel. the WS2812 works from 3.5 V to 5.3V and the perceived brightness of any element would not change. https://cdn-shop.adafruit.com/datasheets/WS2812B.pdf

Comment: @Passerby The supply current varies with the voltage provided. The current measured varies a lot from 3.5 V to 5.3 V. The individual LEDs use widely different maximum currents.

Comment: @MrBuisson The chip will obviously compensate for varying voltage levels along. It's just that your explanation of why or how this compensation occurs is faulty. Read the datasheet, don't just guess how it might work.